# How do I assign an instance of the Image class to an Image control programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, image, controls

Another noob question from me... Apologies!

My initial code would be as follows (this is simplified):

```
Image pic = new Image();

pic.ImageUrl = "~/Images/photo.jpg";
pic.BorderColor = "Black";
```

How can I assign the 'pic' Image object to an Image Control already on my ASP.NET page?

The following doesn't work but illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
MyImageControl = pic;
```

I'm sure there must be an easier solution than:

```
MyImageControl.ImageUrl = pic.ImageUrl;
MyImageControl.BorderColor = pic.BorderColor;
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new control?

Comment: What happens if you just assign the image path to the control

Comment: The example above is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve. The 'pic' object is actually an Image object that is returned from a Dictionary. I then want to assign this Image (or perhaps more specifically, the properties from this Image) to an Image Control which is already present in my .aspx page, without having to explicitly do so for every property.

Comment: @triplestones: When you solve your own question (or come up with an answer) be sure to **post** it as an answer, not as a revision to your current question. Also, make sure you mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Brad Christie: Unfortunately, I don't have a high enough reputation to answer my own questions yet (Need 100 or have to wait 8 hours). I thought it would be better to include the solution in some fashion, rather than forgetting to do it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION** (moved from original post) **:**

I have come up with something which works for me but would still be interested if there is a way to do what I've asked above - My solution is as follows.... Rather than having a blank Image Control in my .aspx page, I changed it for a PlaceHolder instead. Then, in the C# code, I can use the following to include my Image on the page:

```
MyPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(pic);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dynamically put controls on the page you need to do just that. Have a container then add them to the container. If you have some sort of list or array that you are storing the controls in, you just need to iterate through the collection, setting any properties you need and call container.controls.add(control); You will have to do this every post-back as their state will not be kept.

Using an asp:Panel as your container where you want the controls to show up is the easiest way to style and position the controls.